# PBX linked server, table not showing columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

[PBX Linked Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMYBP.jpg)

Good day guys, please assist. I have a linked server to my pbx database but the table is not showing the columns. any idea why?

Comment: the USERID the link is operating under doesn't have the correct permissions to the table?

Comment: Should changes be made to the linked server or to the actual server?